# Iterate through list and find prime numbers and add to another list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, primes

I want to iterate through a list in python, detect prime numbers and then add them to another list.

```
primes = []
nprimes = []
for j in range(0, len(arr)):
    num = arr[j] #my list with numbers to check 

    if num > 1:
        for k in range(2, num):
            if (num % k) == 0:
                nprimes.append(num)
                break
            else:
                primes.append(num)
               
    else:
        print(num, " can't be checked, because its smaller than 1")
```

I have the problem that numbers are always added which are not prime numbers. Also in general the code does not seem to work properly.

Comment: if the number is not divisible by number then you are adding to list and breaking instead of continue to check next number.

Comment: `break` is used in two conditional branches (if and else). Do you think `for k in range(2, num):` actually loop with that setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `num % k == 0` is false you can't say it's `prime` directly you have to wait the whole loop, so move the `else` with the for loop, it'll be executed of no `break` has been encountered which means it's prime

- you may iterate directly on the values `for num in arr`
- you can stop your loop at `sqrt(num)` you won't find a new divisor after that

```
for num in arr:
    if num > 1:
        for k in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
            if num % k == 0:
                nprimes.append(num)
                break
        else:
            primes.append(num)
    else:
        print(num, " can't be checked, because its smaller than 1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm just in the beginning of learning Python. Your answer was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

For learning purposes, let's play with a different approach.  First, I recommend you move your trial division code into its own predicate function `is_prime()`, that returns True or False, so it can be optimized independently of the rest of your code.

Then, I'm going to have `itertools.groupby` divide the list into prime and non-prime sequences that we splice onto the appropriate lists:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number < 2:
        return False

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    for divisor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from random import sample
    from itertools import groupby

    array = sample(range(1, 100), 15)

    primes = []
    composites = []

    for are_prime, numbers in groupby(array, is_prime):
        if are_prime:
            primes.extend(numbers)
        else:
            composites.extend(numbers)

    print("Numbers:", array)
    print("Primes:", primes)
    print("Composites:", composites)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
Numbers: [91, 87, 10, 2, 11, 24, 21, 12, 46, 61, 15, 32, 57, 22, 5]
Primes: [2, 11, 61, 5]
Composites: [91, 87, 10, 24, 21, 12, 46, 15, 32, 57, 22]
%
```

There are lots of ways to go about this problem, many of them educational!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!